# Choosing Clip or Insersect tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip, intersection

I am doing a analysis but I have information which is not available in all disagregation levels. I mean, some data is at a national level, other is at subnational level and other is in district level. I need all the information in district level.

Can I break down data (national and subnational) into district level (in the atributes table)?

If it is posible with QGIS, should I use clip or intersect?

Weighting with a variable or the size of polygon.

If I do it with clip, atributes table is weighted?

I mean transform data (e.g. In Mexico there are 5,600 diabetes deaths at a national level, I require those data at a subnational level weighted by population, or the size of the polygon).

Comment: There are many overlay operators, I think union is is the one you're after but I can't be sure.. what is your specific problem, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't 'dis-aggregate' national data to regional level... it would be like taking the total population of a country and assigning a value to all states/provinces in a country...

Comment: I tried, using intersect. I have 2 layer (shp). One is at subnational level (24 registry in the atribute table) and the other is at a district level (2 registries; name and ID).

Comment: @DPSSpatial, yes I know it. I want to weight the value. For example I have diabetes deaths at a subnational level in one layer, and I have a layer of districts (with population). I would like to weight (estimation) those deaths (subnational) into district level using population.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] which emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: It may help if you include a picture with a few polygons and their attributes to show what you want to happen to them.

Comment: You can't dis-aggregate accurately even by weighting polygons, consider there is a difference between rural, urban and city dwellers - rural people are less likely to be obese as they don't generally have access to fast food but do exercise, urban dwellers are a bit of a mix too as income has an effect on diet which is one of the contributing causes. I live in a fairly 'cheap' area where there are more overweight people than the last suburb I lived in which wasn't a 'cheap' suburb, so giving population only as a normalizing factor weights both evenly even though they are clearly not the same.